# Error with Linq during testing, but not runtime

Tags: c#, linq

In my MVC controller ActionResult, I'm trying to do a merge type of query. This works when I run my code, but the Unit test for the ActionResult is failing.

First I get a `revResources` collection of specific resources, if any. There may be none.

Then I get a list of resources (`projResources`) joined to the `revResources` using DefaultIfEmpty.

During testing, I get an object in memory for `projResources` of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable', but when I try to get a List() I get:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

I'm not sure what's null, or why this works at runtime but not during tests.

During the test, both `db.RoleAssignment` and `db.ProfileSnapshot` have valid records that relate correctly. I tested this by trying just `select ra` or `select p`.

Here's the code in question:

```
var revResources = (from ra in db.RoleAssignment
                    where ra.RoleId == (int)SystemRoles.viewReview
                    select ra)
                .Distinct();
// At Runtime this may have zero (0) records and still functions.

var projResources = (from ra in db.RoleAssignment
                        join p in db.ProfileSnapshot on ra.AssigneeId equals p.ProfileSnapshotId
                        join r in revResources on ra.AssigneeId equals r.AssigneeId into rres
                        from r in rres.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where ra.AssignedToId == review.RequestReview.ProjectSubmissionToReview.ProjectId
                        select new ProfileSnapshotViewModel
                        {
                            ProfileSnapshotId = p.ProfileSnapshotId,
                            Salutation = p.Salutation,
                            FirstName = p.FirstName,
                            MiddleName = p.MiddleName,
                            LastName = p.LastName,
                            Email = p.Email,
                            OriginalSelected = r.RoleAssignmentId != null,
                            Selected = r.RoleAssignmentId != null,
                            RoleAssignmentId = r.RoleAssignmentId
                        }).Distinct();

var assignedResList = projResources.ToList(); // This code fails
```

The StackTrace in the error detail looks like this:

```
at lambda_method(Closure , <>f__AnonymousType17`2 )
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at PublicationSystem.Controllers.ProjectController.ReviewResourceDetails(Guid id) in c:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem\Controllers\ProjectController.cs:line 1200
at PublicationSystem_Test.Controllers.ProjectTests.Project_ReviewResourceDetails_Test() in c:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem_Test\Controllers\ProjectTests.cs:line 74
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
.....
from r in rres.DefaultIfEmpty()
.....
```

You've tolerated the `DefaultIfEmpty()` value, this means that LINQ query may returns NULL for `r` entries .

Otherwise, you tried to access a property of `r` in the select clause

```
 // What should be the value of RoleAssignmentId  if r is null ? 
OriginalSelected = r != null && r.RoleAssignmentId != null,
Selected = r != null && r.RoleAssignmentId != null,
RoleAssignmentId = r == null ? null : r.RoleAssignmentId
```

The exception is raised with ToList() because LINQ queries only run when readen.

There's a very clear topic about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: r.RoleAssignmentId may be null, and I'm okay with that. There will be cases where that is true. Is there a better way to allow that? Why does it work during RunTime, but during testing? (I'm guessing Linq to objects vs Linq to Entity?) Thank you for your help.

Comment: what should be OriginalSelected , Selected  and RoleAssignmentId value when r is null ?

Comment: false, false, and null

Comment: Do mind that depending on how the the `RoleAssignmentId` on `ProfileSnapshotViewModel` is defined `null` may not be a valid value.